# when c++ running in cmd (installed TDM ) i got these error log but no errors in coding

Tags: c++

C:\Users\my~1.SKT\AppData\Local\Temp\ccYyPbqp.o:first1.cpp:(.text+0x1c): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)'
C:\Users\my~1.SKT\AppData\Local\Temp\ccYyPbqp.o:first1.cpp:(.text+0x3b): undefined reference to`std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
C:\Users\my~1.SKT\AppData\Local\Temp\ccYyPbqp.o:first1.cpp:(.text+0x6b): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
C:\Users\my~1.SKT\AppData\Local\Temp\ccYyPbqp.o:first1.cpp:(.rdata$.refptr._ZSt4cout[.refptr._ZSt4cout]+0x0): undefined reference to`std::cout'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Did you perhaps compile with gcc instead of g++?

Comment: i got these when put g++    ......................                                                                                                                                                                                                          
C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: reopening a.exe: Permission denied

C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: final link failed: Permission denied
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Because you're still running your program

Comment: Thank you. After restart the pc g++ is working now